# Multithreading with vectors in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector

Based on [this code](https://gist.github.com/weidagang/5566187), I am trying to do a simple multithread program where the number of threads is determined in the input arguments as `num_threads` and these threads must call the same method with a given input parameters.

The problem arises when `num_items > num_threads` due to the redefinition of `thread_id` (despite the fact that all the threads are joined after their use).Does anyone know where am I failing?

```
vector<thread> thread_id;

int it = num_items/num_threads +  (num_items%num_threads != 0);
for(int i = 0; i < it; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < num_threads; ++j)
        thread_id.push_back(thread(method1, "parameter", i*num_threads + j));

    for(auto& t : threadId)
        t.join();
}
```

The error code is the following:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Invalid argument
```

Comment: A basic counting error. Think about how many loop rounds you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're only always adding to the vector, the old thread handles stay there and you try to re-`join` them (along with the new ones) which is a `std::system_error` [as documented](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join).

Try this at the end of your `j`-loop:

```
thread_id.clear()
```

Also, note that a multiple of `num_threads` will always be created, which will be equal to or greater than `num_items`. You may want to treat the last iteration differently (just add a condition on the value of `i*num_threads + j`).